# Violation of linearity?

Tags: linearity

Can anyone tell me if, based on this image, the linearity assumption is violated in my model?

[image: Graph of Residuals*Predicted Values]

Answer (score 1):

My first assessment is that it may violated linearity, but it definitely violates homoscedasticity.  Consider a variance reducing transformation on the dependent variable, say $ln(y)$ or $\sqrt{y}$. Rerun the regression and plot the residuals again. If you still see a bit of a curve in the data, then consider a non-linear adjustment to the dependent variables.

Comment: +1.  Since the spread is roughly proportional to the predicted value, the logarithm would be a good start.  A suitable [spread vs. level plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=spread+level) will provide a principled point of departure for this exploration.